# How to display special characters in the CMD part of python

Tags: python, special-characters

I have a python program that returns a large amount of info from an API. The info contains special characters like the TM sign and the ★ symbol. When the code is run in the IDLE interface it works exactly as it should returning all information however when the program is run in the CMD-Like interface it crashes because it can not display the symbols. I am using PRINT to output the information. Is there anyway i can make it display the characters in the CMD part?

Comment: you mean it crashes IDLE? what is the CMD-like interface? belongs to IDLE?

Comment: I think he means if he's running his python file straight from CMD. Like `python myscript.py`. Is that right or no?

Comment: No When i say CMD like interface i mean i'm opening the .py file, It looks like CMD but is not. I not sure what you call that.

Comment: The error it gives is "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2605' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Share a part of your code satisfying [mcve] rules, show a printed string example as well. Which [*IDLE* (**I**ntegrated **D**evelopment and **L**earning **E**nvironment) interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#Python) are you using? You can't expect that anyone here is omniscient…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CMD can not display those characters you must convert them